# Get bearer token for calling API in dot net core website secured with B2C Active Directory

Tags: asp.net-core, active-directory, .net-core, jwt, openid-connect

I have created a dot net core web app and secured it with my B2C active directory by following this example:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp

I have also set up a dot net core API project to use jwt bearer token authentication similar to what is described here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/hmahrt/2017/03/06/azure-active-directory-b2c-build-an-asp-net-core-mvc-web-api/

But where and how in the sign in process on the website do I get the token to use for calling the API, and how do I store it and retrieve it later?

I have found an example that seems to do what I'm aiming for but it is based on .net (not .net core), I tried to follow it but haven't been able to get it working:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi

I believe I need to attach to the OnAuthorizationCodeReceived event and from here call an endpoint to get the token, cache it and use that for calling my API, but in my website this event is never even called?

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit: Having just looked again at the sample I based my website on (first link) I see it has been updated to cover this functionality, I will look at this and hopefully it should solve my problem.**

Comment: Any luck so far? I'm stucked in the same situation.

Comment: @PaoloArdissone The example I linked above (first link) has since been updated to include an example of this. The code in `OnAuthorizationCodeReceived` in `WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet/OpenIdConnectOptionsSetup.cs` was basically what I needed

Comment: Thanks! In this example I've found my way out, too!!